# PDFKit Ink Annotations

Tags: ios, swift

I've been working on a PDF editor / annotator using the iOS `PDFKit` framework. When I create annotations using the default options, they end up rendering strangely or not at all (which I've determined means they are rendering just outside the bounds of the annotation, since setting the annotation bounds to say `{0,0,4000,4000}` works). Now the obvious thing here is that I'm setting the bounds incorrectly, however when I subclass `PDFAnnotation` and override the `draw(with:,in:)` method they appear as expected.

*Doesn't work*

```
  // paths made using pdf coordinate space
  let paths: [UIBezierPath] = []
  // find bounding box of all the paths
  let bounds = paths.reduce(CGMutablePath(), { acc, nxt in
    acc.addPath(nxt.cgPath)
    return acc
  }).boundingBoxOfPath.insetBy(dx: -50, dy: -50)

  let border = PDFBorder()
  border.lineWidth = 2.5
  border.style = .solid

  annotation = PDFAnnotation(
    bounds: bounds, 
    forType: .ink, 
    withProperties: [
      PDFAnnotationKey.inklist: paths,
      PDFAnnotationKey.border: border,
      PDFAnnotationKey.color: UIColor.red,
      PDFAnnotationKey.interiorColor: UIColor.red,
    ])

  // Also tried these things / other fiddling but same results
  annotation.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  annotation.shouldDisplay = true
  for path in paths {
    annotation.add(path)
  }
```

*Works great, but doesn't conform to the pdf spec*

```
let paths: [UIBezierPath] = []
let bounds = paths.reduce(CGMutablePath(), { acc, nxt in
  acc.addPath(nxt.cgPath)
  return acc
}).boundingBoxOfPath.insetBy(dx: -50, dy: -50)
annotation = InkAnnotation(bounds: bounds, paths: paths)

/// Overrides draw method to add paths manually
class InkAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {
  var pathList: [UIBezierPath] = []

  public init(bounds: CGRect, paths: [UIBezierPath]) {
    self.pathList = paths
    super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
    context.saveGState()
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(2.5)

    for path in pathList {
      context.addPath(path.cgPath)
      context.strokePath()
    }

    context.strokePath()
    context.restoreGState()
    UIGraphicsPopContext()
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!